# Sorting an array based on time stamp value from JSON Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, timestamp

I'm having timestamp value in my json response and is able to parse that value properly.
Each image is having its own timestamp value and I need to display it in the increasing timestamp value. That means the last updated image should be loaded first in my application.

The timestamp is in the following format in the JSON Response :

```
Brand1{
"FileName": "520120427043622011.jpg",
 "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
}

Brand2{
"FileName": "Kung_Fu_Fingers.jpg",
"UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM"
}

Brand3{
"FileName": "google_logo1.jpg",
"UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
}
```

Can any one please guide me to sort the above three brands images item based on the timestamp value using Javascript or jQuery functions.
I have used sort function after spliting the dat value,but it is sorting the months in alphabetical order only.
Please help me out in finding a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this coming in an array ?. Please share complete JSON.

Comment: { "FileName": "520120427043622011.jpg", "FileUrl": "https://myserver.com/files/basic/anonymous/api/library/74319ed2-a227-4777-be0e-30e6cbbf2a29/document/d3eb0f80-174c-4567-8fa5-477176ea45dc/media/520120427043622011.jpg", "MimeType": "image/jpeg", "TagName": "my_thumb", "FileLength": "243319", "FileDescription": "test", "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 7:33:02 AM" },

Comment: I'm able to parse the response. For sorting based on timestamp value I need help.I have stored the timestamp value in an array.Need to sort that array containing timestamp value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can define insertion-sort, that executes in O(n)-time (best-case, array is sorted), and O(n^2) array is not sorted (worst case):

```
function insertionSort(files,attrToSortBy){
  for(var k=1; k < files.length; k++){
     for(var i=k; i > 0 && new Date(files[i][attrToSortBy]) < 
       new Date(files[i-1][attrToSortBy]); i--){

        var tmpFile = files[i];
        files[i] = files[i-1];
        files[i-1] = tmpFile;

     }
  }

}

var files = [{
     "FileName": "520120427043622011.jpg",
     "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
   },{
     "FileName": "Kung_Fu_Fingers.jpg",
     "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM"
   },{
     "FileName": "google_logo1.jpg",
     "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 12, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
}];

insertionSort(files,"UpdateTimeStamp");

console.log('files: ',files);
```

Comment: This will also return files as [object Object] value when I put alert(files); How will you get the values inside files.

Comment: Can I sort two more arrays using the same time stamp value order?

Comment: This sort-algo can be used with arrays, objects and all other data-structures.

Answer (score 4):

```
var files = [{
"FileName": "520120427043622011.jpg",
 "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
},{
"FileName": "Kung_Fu_Fingers.jpg",
"UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM"
},{
"FileName": "google_logo1.jpg",
"UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
}];

files.sort(function(a, b){
    var d1 = new Date(a.UpdateTimeStamp);
    var d2 = new Date(b.UpdateTimeStamp);
    return d1-d2; // d2-d1 for descending order
});
```

EDIT:

For array of timestamps

```
var updateTimeStamps = ["Aug 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM","Jun 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM" ,"May 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"];

updateTimeStamps.sort(function(a, b){
    var d1 = new Date(a);
    var d2 = new Date(b);
    return d1-d2; // d2-d1 for descending order
});

console.log(updateTimeStamps);
```

EDIT 2: 
For keeping two arrays and sorting

```
var imgs = ["img1", "img2", "img3"];
var times = ["Jul 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM","Jan 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM" ,"Feb 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"];

var sorting = [];
times.sort(function(a, b){
    var d1 = new Date(a);
    var d2 = new Date(b);
    var d =  d1-d2; // d2-d1 for descending order
    sorting.push(d);
    return d;
});

imgs.sort(function(a, b){
    return sorting.shift();
});

console.log(times);
console.log(imgs);
```

Comment: callback({
      "Brands": [
    [{
    "FileName": "520120427043622011.jpg",
     "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
    },{
    "FileName": "Kung_Fu_Fingers.jpg",
   "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM"
   },{
   "FileName": "google_logo1.jpg",
    "UpdateTimeStamp": "Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"
    }];
  })

Comment: I have tried the above code previously and it will return in alphabetical order only.Eg: Aug,June,May like wise and not based on the above response.

Comment: Can you please explain the tokens you are using.What all are the values I need to use in my code.I have stored the timestamp data in updatetimestamp array. In the above code what are the value for files,a,b?

Comment: I need to sort the array - updatetimestamp  which contains the fetched timestamp value.

Comment: please share a sample array

Comment: updatetimestamp ={"Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM","Jun 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM"
,"Jun 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"};

Comment: I'm getting sorted values in "files". How to retreive that value one by one.

Comment: use correct notation for array - `["Aug 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM","Jun 5, 2013 6:51:12 AM" ,"May 10, 2013 8:31:23 AM"]` . See the edited answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31532/discussion-between-abin-koshy-cheriyan-and-tracevipin)

Comment: Thanks tracevipin.Thank you ver much.It worked perfectly as expected. :) :) :)

Comment: Can I ask one more doubt,I'm having the sorted timestamp value now.Also an arra named image having the parsed image values.How can I sort the image array based on the sorted timestamp value.

Comment: are you receiving timestamps and imagelinks as two separate  arrays ?

Comment: Yes. It is coming from response and I'm storing images and timestamps in separate arrays.

Comment: Please store it in a single array if possible, like I have done in the first part of the answer.

Comment: No. I need to get the image url and timestamp details.Then based on timestamp order,sort the images array and display it.

Comment: In the same example, I'm getting responses from JSON and parsing it to get the following array values.