# Unable to sort date time in javascript with format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

Tags: javascript, sorting, datetime

I am not able to sort by latest date time in javascript.

Below is my json :

```
let jsonStr = [{id:1,date:"04/04/2017 17:47"},
               {id:2,date:"05/01/2015 12:35"},
               {id:3,date:"31/02/2017 10:00"},
               {id:4,date:"31/02/2017 12:00"}];
```

Expected result : Latest date time should be first in the list

- 04/04/2017 17:47
- 31/02/2017 12:00
- 31/02/2017 10:00
- 05/01/2015 12:35

Current result :

- 31/02/2017 12:00
- 31/02/2017 10:00
- 04/04/2017 17:47
- 05/01/2015 12:35

Sorting logic that I used :

```
function sortFunction(a,b){  
   var dateA = new Date(a.date).getTime();
   var dateB = new Date(b.date).getTime();
   return dateB > dateA ? 1 : -1; 
}; 

let jsonStr = [{id:1,date:"04/04/2017 17:47"},
               {id:2,date:"05/01/2015 12:35"},
               {id:3,date:"31/02/2017 10:00"},
               {id:4,date:"31/02/2017 12:00"}];

jsonStr.sort(sortFunction);​
```

Reference links that I used :

- [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)
- [Sorting an array based on time stamp value from JSON Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026409/sorting-an-array-based-on-time-stamp-value-from-json-response)
- [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://codepen.io/weedenwright/pen/gkvcL

Comment: your id 3 and 4 has the wrong date that is not possible 31/02/2017

Comment: Did you check what `new Date()` gives for your strings?

Comment: actually javascript `Date` expect format as `MM/dd/yyyy` so 3rd and 4th are invalid date and if you try to use `new Date(..)` method it will return `invalid date`, try to send the json date from your server as `MM/dd/yyy hh:mm` and the links you are referencing will work for you.

Comment: try fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/g1tgp04h/

Comment: @DeepakSharma—are you sure about that? Have you checked the format [*specified in ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not interpreting the date the way you think it is. For example,

```
console.log(new Date("05/01/2015 12:35"));
```

produces for me:

```
Date 2017-05-01T19:35:00.000Z
```

which shows that it's expecting the date to be in MM/dd/yyyy format.

---

You can either roll your own solution or use one of the libraries out there. There are a lot of solutions available. I personally like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which allows [date format strings](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Another example, quoted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38593735/367865), adds date parsing format control to strings:

> ```
> String.prototype.toDate = function(format)
> {
>   var normalized      = this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-');
>   var normalizedFormat= format.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-');
>   var formatItems     = normalizedFormat.split('-');
>   var dateItems       = normalized.split('-');
>
>   var monthIndex  = formatItems.indexOf("mm");
>   var dayIndex    = formatItems.indexOf("dd");
>   var yearIndex   = formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
>   var hourIndex     = formatItems.indexOf("hh");
>   var minutesIndex  = formatItems.indexOf("ii");
>   var secondsIndex  = formatItems.indexOf("ss");
>
>   var today = new Date();
>
>   var year  = yearIndex>-1  ? dateItems[yearIndex]    : today.getFullYear();
>   var month = monthIndex>-1 ? dateItems[monthIndex]-1 : today.getMonth()-1;
>   var day   = dayIndex>-1   ? dateItems[dayIndex]     : today.getDate();
>
>   var hour    = hourIndex>-1      ? dateItems[hourIndex]    : today.getHours();
>   var minute  = minutesIndex>-1   ? dateItems[minutesIndex] : today.getMinutes();
>   var second  = secondsIndex>-1   ? dateItems[secondsIndex] : today.getSeconds();
>
>   return new Date(year,month,day,hour,minute,second);
> };
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> "22/03/2016 14:03:01".toDate("dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss");
> "2016-03-29 18:30:00".toDate("yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss");
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The first rule with dates is do not use the Date constructor (or Date.parse) to parse strings. Do it manually. A library can help, but if you only have to deal with one format, then a simple function will suffice.

You can convert the strings to a format that sorts, say ISO 8601, or convert them to dates and sort those, e.g.

```js
var data = [{id:1,date:"04/04/2017 17:47"},
            {id:2,date:"05/01/2015 12:35"},
            {id:3,date:"31/02/2017 10:00"},
            {id:4,date:"31/02/2017 12:00"}];
            
function parseDMYhm(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2], b[1]-1, b[2], b[3], b[4]);  
}

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseDMYhm(a.date) - parseDMYhm(b.date);
});

console.log(data);
```

Note that the parse function does not validate the date values, so 31/02/2017 will be treated as 3 March, 2017. If you want to validate the date values, that is one more line of code.

An alternative to sort as strings might be:

```js
var data = [{id:1,date:"04/04/2017 17:47"},
            {id:2,date:"05/01/2015 12:35"},
            {id:3,date:"31/02/2017 10:00"},
            {id:4,date:"31/02/2017 12:00"}];
            
// Reformat DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm as YYYY-MM-DDTHH-mm
function formatStringAsISO(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return b[2] + '-' + b[1] + '-' + b[0] + 'T' + b[3] + ':' + b[4];
}

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return formatStringAsISO(a.date).localeCompare(formatStringAsISO(b.date));
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because some of your dates are returning `Invalid date` when put inside the date object `new Date()`

Eg: **31/02/2017** is not a valid date

If you enter the correct dates, it will give you the right output.

Comment: Sure it is. [Some countries write their dates with the day first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country).

Comment: even then thats not a valid date 31 February 2017 does not exist in the calendar and javascript will return Invalid date when processing that @Ouroborus

Comment: No, it isn't a valid date as far as you or I are concerned. But assuming the dates were formatted the way Javascript was expecting, it will make a best effort: `new Date("02/31/2000")` ends up as `Date 1900-03-03T08:00:00.000Z` for me.

Comment: @RahulArora—for any format other than that specified in ECMA-262, browsers can parse strings any way they like, so 31/2/2017 may return invalid date or a Date for 3 March, 2017, or 1 July 2019.